# counting in three joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables. The first one is `PrivteOwner` and has 5 columns (`ownerno, fname, lname, address, telno`), the second one is `PropertyForRent` that has 10 columns (`propertyno, street, city, postcode, type, rooms, rent, ownerno, staffno, branchno`) and the third one is `Viewing` with 4 columns (`clientno, propertyno, viewdate, comment`).

I want to find the owner who has the most properties without a viewing. My code is as below:

```
    SELECT 
        CONCAT (A.fname, ' ', A.lname) AS OwnerName, 
        A.ownerno, B.propertyno, B.ownerno
    FROM 
        PrivateOwner AS A 
    INNER JOIN 
        PropertyforRent AS B ON A.ownerno = B.ownerno
    LEFT JOIN
        viewing AS C

   SELECT 
        ownerno, COUNT(ownerno), viewdate
   FROM 
       Max_Property
       GROUP BY ownerno
       ORDER BY COUNT(ownerno) DESC
   WHERE
       ROWNUM = 1 and viewdate IS NULL;
```

Does this code work correctly? If yes how we can write it efficiently?

Comment: You obviously haven't even tried to execute this code.   It should raise a syntax error.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not a dataset. I just face a question without any more information.

Comment: Since it's sql-server you can use some common table expressions and start by making one which sums views by owner, and then another which sums properties for rent by owner, and then join those two CTEs into your main table of owners and you'll have what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very difficult to answer question if you don't provide data definition, data or your expected result.

Anyway, from your description I think this might get you your desired result.

```sql
SELECT
    TOP 1
    PrivteOwner.ownerno,
    PrivteOwner.fname,
    PrivteOwner.lname,
    COUNT(ViewNumber) AS PropertyNumber
FROM
(
    SELECT
        PropertyForRent.propertyno AS propertyno
        , COUNT(Viewing.propertyno) AS ViewNumber
    FROM PropertyForRent
    LEFT JOIN Viewing ON Viewing.propertyno = PropertyForRent.propertyno
    GROUP BY PropertyForRent.propertyno
) AS NoView
JOIN PropertyForRent ON PropertyForRent.propertyno = NoView.propertyno
JOIN PrivteOwner ON PrivteOwner.ownerno = PropertyForRent.ownerno
WHERE ViewNumber = 0
GROUP BY PrivteOwner.ownerno,
    PrivteOwner.fname,
    PrivteOwner.lname
ORDER BY PropertyNumber DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind assistance.